# PHPWord addListItem loop corrupts the document

Tags: php, phpword

```
$cInc = json_decode($inc);

$c = count((array)$cInc);

for ($x = 0; $x < $c; $x++)
{
    $section->addListItem($cInc[$x]);
}
```

So I want to loop the array `$cInc` to a List Item and somehow the loop corrupts the document.

Comment: Please add the error you get to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you are wrong using **count**

*The count() function returns the number of elements in an array*

so you dont need array **inside** count

just

```
$cInc = json_decode($inc);

$c = count($cInc);

for ($x = 0; $x < $c; $x++)
{
    $section->addListItem($cInc[$x]);
}
```

or u can use foreach if you dont know how many array that you have

```
$cInc = json_decode($inc);

foreach ($cInc as $val)
{
    $section->addListItem($val);
}
```